# how to reading residence.dat file C++ using striping algorithm

Tags: c++

I have to read data from  two .dat files but I have problem with my output  function to console  and my C++ Skill is still rusty can someone help ?

> Read a subset of the address records from residences.dat using striping. For n >processes, each process evaluates a unique subset of
>   records based on every nth record. The number of records in this
>   subset should be approximately #-of-residence-records /#-of-processes. Across all the parallel processes used no address should be omitted and >none should be processed more than once. Also
>   note that only ONE record at a time should be stored in memory by any
>   process; don’t read the entire dataset into a data structure in memory
>   since this is entirely unnecessary and consumes too much RAM!

data example

```
329267.349 4847214.382
318141.019 4851350.892
319526.06 4850474.347
322666.48 4840244.995
316578.529 4837299.827
320090.607 4840439.088



    //read file and populate the vectors


     ifstream foodbankFile("/Users/abdallaelnajjar/Documents/XCodeProjects/cpp_projects/MPI_Project2/foodbanks.dat");
        ifstream residenceFile("/Users/abdallaelnajjar/Documents/XCodeProjects/cpp_projects/MPI_Project2/residences.dat");

        // populate datavector
       std::vector<Foodbank> foodbankData((std::istream_iterator<Foodbank>(foodbankFile)),
                                      std::istream_iterator<Foodbank>());
       //std::vector<Residence> residenceData((std::istream_iterator<Residence>(residenceFile)),
                                      //std::istream_iterator<Residence>());


        std::vector<double> distancess;


        string file_contents;
        Residence res;
        int numProcs = 1;
        int recCount = 0;



    //pseudo code that I trying to implement 
    // While(there are more records){
   // If record count % numProcs == myID
    //   ProcessRecord
   // else
    //   Increment file stream pointer forward one record without processing
   // Increment Record Count
    //}

          int numLines = 1;
        while(!residenceFile.eof())
        {


            residenceFile >> res.x >>res.y;

            //distancess.push_back(populate_distancesVector(res,foodbankData));
            if ( recCount % numProcs == numLines)
            {
                //call the  process
                distancess.push_back(populate_distancesVector(res,foodbankData));
            }
            else
                ++numLines;
            ++recCount;
        }
```

Comment: Tell us the exact problem

Comment: I think fstream is not writing .dat file and output it as to struct Foodbank x and y

Comment: Unless you want everything on one line you probably want a newline `<< "\n"` at the end of the `cout` statement.  There's no file writing going on at all in your program, did you mean reading?

Comment: yes I want to read files

Comment: just I don't have any output or any exception??

Comment: In addition to adding newlines at the end of your lines you can try adding `cout.flush();` after the while loop to make sure any buffered output is flushed.  It's also entirely possible the file is never opened or the reading is failing.  Add more debug statements or use a debugger to trace through what is happening.

Comment: How come your fstream variable is residenceData and you are reading through residenceFile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're most likely getting no results because your file isn't being opened.** Most likely, you aren't pointing to it correctly when you initialize the `fstream`. This is why you aren't seeing any output.

**You should always check to see that your `streams` are open (accessible) before doing anything else with them.** To check that it has been opened correctly:

```
if (foodBankData.is_open()) {
    Foodbank f;

    while(foodbankData >> f.x >> f.y )
    {
        cout<< "X"<< f.x << "Y" <<f.y << endl; //don't forget the newline here
    }
}
else {
    cerr << "Error opening input file!" << endl;
    exit(1);//call the error function or something else here.
}
```

Comment: @ninjaDeveloper: Wait ... I solved your original problem, and once that was done, you unaccepted my answer, edited your question to reflect your new problem, and then implicitly tells me to help you with your completely new question? Fascinating. Good luck getting help with an attitude like that, buddy.

Comment: i ask new Question all I get more Pseudocode with no code.i am very sorry for that but reall just need working code

Comment: do you know you are right you deserve the point because you are only one how give me code

Comment: @ninjaDeveloper: I see that you're offering a bounty on edited question. If so, then you reserve the right to whom it is assigned, as it is a completely different problem now. Something to note in future is that you should have asked a new question to avoid problems like this. That aside, I'll see how best I can help you as my original answer has no bearing on the current question.

Comment: @ninjaDeveloper: "Deserving" is quite subjective. No one deserves anything except that which they are due. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: thank  I asked new question and I post the new code & everyone give me new Pseudocode  after Pseudocode without correct my code